# can't open device: Too many open files Error

Tags: linux, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, spi

Hi I Have Terrible codes in Raspberry Pi 3. I am trying to read 4 RC522 Module and i can do it. But after few minutes I got "can't open device: Too many open files" Error, and my while loop terminated.

I didnt share all the functions. I guess important part is while loop. I create instance in every loop. I guess this is big mistake. I cant add delay. I tried assign null to my object but i got still same error. My Codes are Below

Note: I have 4 SPI address, and i create instance with them.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
import time
import sys
import os
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import MFRC522
import signal
from time import gmtime, strftime
from time import sleep
import requests
#import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
#import xmltodict, json
from lxml import objectify
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
continue_reading = True

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(37, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(13, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(15, GPIO.OUT)

# Capture SIGINT for cleanup when the script is aborted
def end_read(signal,frame):
    global continue_reading
    print "Ctrl+C captured, ending read."
    continue_reading = False
    GPIO.cleanup()

kullanici = "xxxx"
sifre = "xxxx"
birim = "xxxx"
ogrKEY = " "


def end_read(signal,frame):
    global continue_reading
    print "Ctrl+C captured, ending read."
    continue_reading = False
    GPIO.cleanup()


# Hook the SIGINT
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, end_read)

# Create an object of the class MFRC522
#
adresler = ["/dev/spidev0.0", "/dev/spidev0.1", "/dev/spidev1.0","/dev/spidev1.1"]

# Welcome message
print "Welcome to the MFRC522 data read example"
print "Press Ctrl-C to stop."
j = 0
# This loop keeps checking for chips. If one is near it will get the UID and authenticate
while continue_reading:
    MIFAREReader = None
    pin = 0
    if j == 100:
       j = 0
    i = j % 4

    if i == 0:
    MIFAREReader =  MFRC522.MFRC522(adresler[0], 16)
        pin = 15
    elif i == 1:
    MIFAREReader =  MFRC522.MFRC522(adresler[1], 18)
        pin = 13
    elif i == 2:
        MIFAREReader = MFRC522.MFRC522(adresler[2], 33)
        pin = 7
    else:
        MIFAREReader = MFRC522.MFRC522(adresler[3], 31)
        pin = 37


    # Scan for cards 
    (status,TagType) = MIFAREReader.MFRC522_Request(MIFAREReader.PICC_REQIDL)

    # If a card is found
    if status == MIFAREReader.MI_OK:
       print "Card detected"

       # Get the UID of the card
       (status,uid) = MIFAREReader.MFRC522_Anticoll()

       # If we have the UID, continue
       if status == MIFAREReader.MI_OK:
              # print "su okuyucudan okundu" % i
           # Print UID
           print "Card read UID: "+str(uid[0])+","+str(uid[1])+","+str(uid[2])+","+str(uid[3])

           # This is the default key for authentication
           key = [0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF]
           # Select the scanned tag
           MIFAREReader.MFRC522_SelectTag(uid)

           # Authenticate
           status = MIFAREReader.MFRC522_Auth(MIFAREReader.PICC_AUTHENT1A, 10, key, uid)

           # Check if authenticated
           if status == MIFAREReader.MI_OK:
               MIFAREReader.MFRC522_Read(10)
           ogrKEY = MIFAREReader.returnOGR()
                   sonuc =  parser(ogrKEY)
                   if sonuc == True:
            openTurnsTile(pin)
                   else:
            sonuc = personelKontrol(ogrKey)
                        if sonuc == True:
                openTurnsTile(pin)
               MIFAREReader.MFRC522_StopCrypto1()
           else:
               print "Authentication error"
    j = j + 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create the MFRC522 object it actually calls `spi.openSPI()` but never closes it. This python library is good for single instance but now that you are dealing with multiple instance where FDs are opened, needs to be closed as well using `spi.closeSPI()`, else you will get the error "Too many open FDs".

To check how many [open FDs](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-procfs-file-descriptors.html) are there for your PID.

Comment: there is no closeSPI function :(

Comment: Sorry i found, closeSPI function is in spi library naturally, sorry for this :) thank you.

Comment: if this helped, can you please give up vote? Thanks :)